# Cron a PHP loop that requires page refresh

Tags: php

I have a PHP crawler that fires from crontab a few times a day

```
php crawler.php
```

In `crawler.php`, I query a database for my sites, then loop and check them:

```
foreach ($mysql_results as .. ) {
    // curl and check html for my checks
    // each site takes about 30sec
}
```

I've begun changing the logic, to instead just do one site per php execution, finish, then re-fire the script and run the next site

```
// get offset from database
// based on offset get single site from database
// curl and check html for my checks
// increase offset by one
// close database
// run this page again until no more sites are left
shell_exec('php '.__FILE__);
```

Everything fine until, of course, that last line. `shell_exec` waits for the execution to finish.. If I'm not mistaken, my php file is not firing independently as a sibling process - it's just stacking within itself, which is what I'm trying to get away from.

Is there anyway in php, to fire a php cli process - without waiting? Or is my logic just totally off?

Comment: change your execution to become a while loop, fetch new records from mysql after doing the first set of "work", avoid recursivly calling the same script. eg `while( $sites = get_more_sites() ){foreach( $sites as $site){...}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it's executes the script synchronously.

Instead, better approach would be to have cron run a script once a minute and than have a script update "last crawl date" for a particular website in the database.

That way each new script run should just pick up the site with the oldest "last crawl date" and process it.

This way, each script run would be completely independent and you could have multiple php processes running in parallel.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes! That's absolutely right. The code i currently have would actually adapt to that as the script it associates 'the current scan' to the current hour.. so after x scans it would stop anyways. wow. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`pcntl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php), this is the PHP equivalent of the POSIX `execve()` system call. It replaces the current process with the new program.

```
pcntl_exec("/usr/bin/php", ["php", __FILE__]);
```

Comment: ah fantastic. I wondered if something like that existed. that's perfect, thank you so much..